# Magento Em megaMenu extension not linking categories

Tags: extensions

I'm using em mega menu extension for my project . mega menu is working fine but its not linking products .

Comment: Hi and welcome to Magento SE. Unfortunately questions about 3rd party modules/extensions are off topic here. I suggest you contact the extension developer directly to get some help

Comment: @RaphaelatDigitalPianism Thanks for your comment . actually i also sent an email to theme support but they will reply after a day . and i'm in a hurry to finish this project

Comment: @rameez.hashmi can you see `em thems or em menu manager` in backend, you have to go there and link the category to menu.... are you using something like this : http://www.emthemes.com/commercial-magento-extensions/em-mega-menu.html ?

Comment: @BabyinMagento Yes i am using em themes . Actually in menu manager when i use drag and drop feature for creating menu it shows only default category not the sub category of default category . Thanks for your response

Comment: @rameez.hashmi not sure which mega menu you are using, i used `em mega menu` before, instead you can give `sub-category url link` to menu , so that when you click on `menu` it will display `sub-category`

Comment: @BabyinMagento i am also using em mega menu . mafhcanada.com project is live

Comment: @rameez.hashmi fine, try giving `sub-category url` for `menu` and check.....

Comment: @BabyinMagento i tried giving url of sub category and its redirecting me to 404 not found page

Comment: give full url , `category-url/sub-category-url.html` or `site-url/category-url/sub-category-url.html`

Comment: @BabyinMagento i give this url {{store url=catalog/category/view/s/full-frame/id/17/}} . now its working fine . Thank you so much . you are master in magento

Comment: @rameez.hashmi one more suggestion,  this url is not seo friendly [ {{store url=catalog/category/view/s/full-frame/id/17/}}  ] , so you need to reindex once for getting real url.....

Comment: @BabyinMagento actually the real url on browser is http://mafhcanada.com/index.php/catalog/category/view/s/full-frame/id/17/

Comment: @rameez.hashmi once you complete reindexing those url will change, that time again you may need to replace old urls by new urls,  check this once : http://www.hostknox.com/tutorials/magento/index-management

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what all you need to do is , you have to link the menu with category urls, as like `site-url/category-url.html`